# Mark a variable as used for benchmarking with Clang

Tags: c++, clang

In C++, using Clang is there a directive to force Clang to calculate the value of a variable and not optimise it away if it is unused. This is for benchmarking. Or alternatively is there a black box function that Clang will never optimise that I could pass the variable to for the same effect?

I've used empty inline assembly for this in the past but I'd rather use something designed for this purpose.

Comment: Without any guarantee: `auto volatile ignore = f();`. Compilers are really fearful to optimize away volatile-specified variables.

Comment: AFAIK the safest way is to stick to these magic assembly lines....
Google Benchmark does it as well and I'd say if there was a significantly better/different way they would have changed their `DoNotOptimize` by now. for ref: https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/f85304e4e3a0e4e1bf15b91720df4a19e90b589f/include/benchmark/benchmark.h#L315

Comment: Ok if Google Benchmark does it that is good enough for me I guess.